# Self-built home server periodically freezes

Tags: linux, freeze, home-server

A few years back I built a home server which periodically freezes and becomes unresponsive. I am at a complete loss for what could be causing it.  I believe it to be a hardware problem, but I don't know for sure.  I have been unable to get any proper diagnostics or log files...most of the time it freezes up and leaves no trace of what went wrong. Three times out of the maybe a hundred times that it has frozen it has produced an error message on the screen. I've attached low resolution cell camera pictures of the errors here.  The common issue seems to be `watchdog: BUG: soft lockup - CPU#3 stuck for 22s!`:

[Imgur album of error pics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tu7qc.jpg)

Note that I believe the reference to EmbyServer to be misleading. While I've never had the error messages disaplay without it running, I've had this freeze happen without emby running (or even docker, in which all my services run for that matter).

I've tried every software solution I can find, including trying a different Linux distribution (both Debian and Ubuntu server).  I've tried using kdump, with no result. My original setup used an m.2 ssd + hdd; I've also reinstalled the OS from the SSD to the HDD with no change.

Nothing in the journalctl logs show anything suspicious at the time of the crash.

At this point, I'm ready to just assume that my CPU (Ryzen 3 1200 3.1GHz Quad Core AM4) is bad and needs replacing, but before I just blindly start purchasing new hardware parts, I thought I'd check with the Stack Exchange community to see if there's anything that you could think of being amiss.

Comment: When I do a search for `watchdog: BUG: soft lockup` I find [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/929817/nmi-watchdog-bug-soft-lockup-cpu2-stuck-for-23s-nvidia-smi566). What did you find when doing a search? Did you try any of the things you found (except for re-installing Linux)?

Comment: In general it seems that error just means "the cpu is in an infinite loop" and is more describing a symptom rather than a cause. In the link that you posted the error specifically relates to Nvidia, which is backed up by what the user was doing when the error occurred. I'm willing to try it... I have an Nvidia gpu but my server is headless, so I'm not super optimistic.

Comment: Just to update this:  It looks like there is an issue with Ryzen CPUS, Linux Kernels, and C-State.  Last week, I disabled C-States from the bios, and it hasn't crashed again since.  This isn't really definitive yet however...if it stays stable I will update this as solved.